# Herança e polimorfismo em python

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from random import randint

class Nomes(object):
    def __init__(self, qtd_letras):
        self.letras = qtd_letras
        self.alfabeto = (('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'), ('A','B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L','M','N','O','P','Q', 'R','S','T','U','V','W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'))
    def nome(self):
        nome = ''
        while True:
            aleat_letra = randint(0, len(self.alfabeto[1]) - 1)
            nome += self.alfabeto[1][aleat_letra]
            aleat_letra = randint(0, len(self.alfabeto[0]) - 1)
            nome += self.alfabeto[0][aleat_letra]
            if len(nome) >= self.letras:
                nome = nome[0:self.letras]
                break
        return nome


class Sobrenomes(Nomes):
    def __init__(self, qtd_letras):
        super(Sobrenomes, self).__init__(qtd_letras)
    def sobrenomes(self):
        super(Sobrenomes, self).nome()


a = Nomes(5)
print(a.nome())

b = Sobrenomes(5)
print(b.sobrenome())
```

```
Caio
None
```

Esse código possui 02 classes, sendo elas a classe Nomes e a classe Sobrenomes (sendo que a classe Sobrenomes herda todas as caracteristicas da classe Nome)

Quando eu instancio a classe Nomes e utilizo o metodo .nome():

```
>>> meu_nome =  Nomes(6)
>>> print(meu_nome.nome())
>>> Carlos
```

Porém quando utilizo quando é com classe Sobrenomes complica:

```
>>> meu_sobrenome = Sobrenomes(8)
>>> print(meu_sobrenome.sobrenome())
>>> none
```

O valor retornado é none mas... a classe Sobrenomes herda tudo da classe Nomes! a unica mudança foi no nome do unico metodo mas mesmo assim, o metodo sobrenome da classe Sobrenomes herda as caracteristicas do metodo nome da classe mãe Nomes.
N estou mais entendendo.

Comment: Você já tentou executar sobre come com o parâmetro 6 para ver se o resultado será o mesmo?

Answer (score 3):

A única coisa que tive que alterar no seu código para funcionar foi

```
def sobrenomes(self):
  return super(Sobrenomes, self).nome()
```

Tive que colocar o `return` no método "sobrenomes", e coloque o "s" em "sobrenome" já que o seu método esta no plural

```
from random import randint

class Nomes(object):

    def __init__(self, qtd_letras):
        self.letras = qtd_letras
        self.alfabeto = (('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'), ('A','B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L','M','N','O','P','Q', 'R','S','T','U','V','W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'))

    def nome(self):
        nome = ''
        while True:
            aleat_letra = randint(0, len(self.alfabeto[1]) - 1)
            nome += self.alfabeto[1][aleat_letra]
            aleat_letra = randint(0, len(self.alfabeto[0]) - 1)
            nome += self.alfabeto[0][aleat_letra]
            if len(nome) >= self.letras:
                nome = nome[0:self.letras]
                break
        return nome


class Sobrenomes(Nomes):

    def __init__(self, qtd_letras):
        super(Sobrenomes, self).__init__(qtd_letras)

    def sobrenomes(self):
      return super(Sobrenomes, self).nome()


a = Nomes(5)
print(a.nome())

b = Sobrenomes(5)
print(b.sobrenomes())
```

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Heranca-e-polimorfismo-em-python/10462?id=10462)

Answer (score 0):

Na função `sobrenome` está faltando o `return`

```
    def sobrenome(self):
        return super(Sobrenomes, self).nome()
```